# Kendo Gantt timeline does not occupy full width on first load

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-angular-ui

I have this weird problem where the Gantt timeline on its first load does not occupy the whole width.

[image]

but when I resize the window, the width is automatically fixed.

Here's my html:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ProjectsScheduleController">
    <div class="content-container schedule-content-container " ng-class="{ 'hasProjectInfo' : projects.currentProject != null}">
        <div id="schedule-container">
            <div kendo-gantt k-options="ganttOptions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue can´t be reproduced with the code sample you provide. What I can tell is that switching theme usualy have similar behavior.

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS that could interfere?

Comment: this is already fix. got an issue when reloading using Empty Cache. but when loading it using redirection. the width is correct